# [TypeScript]: Typing a class on the `globalThis` variable

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to add type definitions to variable on `globalThis` that should act as a class. In JavaScript:

```js
globalThis.X = class {
  ...
}
```

I am having trouble adding the type definitions on the globalThis object to allow this to work.

```js
declare global {
  module globalThis {
    // Doesn't work. TypeScript error in declaration file.
    var X = (class {
      ...
    })

    // Doesn't work. TypeScript error on usage.
    class X {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

```
const x = new globalThis.X();

console.log(x.value); // This works and will return the actual value on x.
```

See [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-darkness-3uoj3i?file=/src/index.ts) for example reproduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TypeScript, by adding `new` before the function definition it will act as a constructor. In your example:

```
declare global {
  module globalThis {
    interface XType {
      value: number;
    }
    var X: new (x?: number, y?: number) => XType;
  }
}
```

Then when you try to use `new globalThis.X()`, you should get a type safe variable as the output of type `XType`.